# java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?):(adding netstat -a)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I am using tomcat 7.x , when I am starting my server after some time I am getting following error.

```
Sep 17, 2011 4:46:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:457)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:452)
```

after this I checked all my leaked connection and other resources, my application is completely fine.

but when this error comes, I have to restart my computer. Even after restart the server this is not recoverable.

I am pasting my netstat -a, before this issue comes and after the issue comes.

Before.
///////////////////////////////

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\abhi>netstats -n
'netstats' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\abhi>netstat -n

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10501        127.0.0.1:50123        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10502        127.0.0.1:50124        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49158        127.0.0.1:49165        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49162        127.0.0.1:49166        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49165        127.0.0.1:49158        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49166        127.0.0.1:49162        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49169        127.0.0.1:49170        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49170        127.0.0.1:49169        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50123        127.0.0.1:10501        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50124        127.0.0.1:10502        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50197        127.0.0.1:50198        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50198        127.0.0.1:50197        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50332        127.0.0.1:50333        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50333        127.0.0.1:50332        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50854        127.0.0.1:50855        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50855        127.0.0.1:50854        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51123        127.0.0.1:51122        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51126        127.0.0.1:51125        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51361        127.0.0.1:51362        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51372        127.0.0.1:51374        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51416        127.0.0.1:51417        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51417        127.0.0.1:51416        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51526        127.0.0.1:51525        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51682        127.0.0.1:51681        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52057        127.0.0.1:52058        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52060        127.0.0.1:52061        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52119        127.0.0.1:52118        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52253        127.0.0.1:52254        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52254        127.0.0.1:52253        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52761        127.0.0.1:52762        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52762        127.0.0.1:52761        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52841        127.0.0.1:52842        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52842        127.0.0.1:52841        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53027        127.0.0.1:53028        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53028        127.0.0.1:53027        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53030        127.0.0.1:53031        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53031        127.0.0.1:53030        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53195        127.0.0.1:53196        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53256        127.0.0.1:53257        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53285        127.0.0.1:53284        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53413        127.0.0.1:53414        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53437        127.0.0.1:53438        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53438        127.0.0.1:53437        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53481        127.0.0.1:53480        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53489        127.0.0.1:53488        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53523        127.0.0.1:53524        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53524        127.0.0.1:53523        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53526        127.0.0.1:53527        FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53527        127.0.0.1:53526        CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53579        127.0.0.1:53580        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53580        127.0.0.1:53579        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53591        127.0.0.1:53590        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53594        127.0.0.1:53593 
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53725        127.0.0.1:53726        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53754        127.0.0.1:53755        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53755        127.0.0.1:53754        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53799        127.0.0.1:53800        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53802        127.0.0.1:53803        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53805        127.0.0.1:53806        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53843        127.0.0.1:53844        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53844        127.0.0.1:53843        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53846        127.0.0.1:53847        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53849        127.0.0.1:53850        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53860        127.0.0.1:53861        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53869        127.0.0.1:53870        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53876        127.0.0.1:53875        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53878        127.0.0.1:53879        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53930        127.0.0.1:53931        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53971        127.0.0.1:53972        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53975        127.0.0.1:53976        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53976        127.0.0.1:53975        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53978        127.0.0.1:53977        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54018        127.0.0.1:54017        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54019        127.0.0.1:54021        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54036        127.0.0.1:54037        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54039        127.0.0.1:54040        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54043        127.0.0.1:54041        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54085        127.0.0.1:54086        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54198        127.0.0.1:54199        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54201        127.0.0.1:54200        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54203        127.0.0.1:54202        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54205        127.0.0.1:54204        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54207        127.0.0.1:54206        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54209        127.0.0.1:54208        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54216        127.0.0.1:54217        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54219        127.0.0.1:54218        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54221        127.0.0.1:54220        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54223        127.0.0.1:54222        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54225        127.0.0.1:54224        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54227        127.0.0.1:54226        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54229        127.0.0.1:54228        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54231        127.0.0.1:54230        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54233        127.0.0.1:54232        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54244        127.0.0.1:54243        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54247        127.0.0.1:54246        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54249        127.0.0.1:54250        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54252        127.0.0.1:54253        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54255        127.0.0.1:54256        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54259        127.0.0.1:54258        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54273        127.0.0.1:54274        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54274        127.0.0.1:54273        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54277        127.0.0.1:54276        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54280        127.0.0.1:54279        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54283        127.0.0.1:54282        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54286        127.0.0.1:54285        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54289        127.0.0.1:54288        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54291        127.0.0.1:54292        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54292        127.0.0.1:54291        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54294        127.0.0.1:54295        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54295        127.0.0.1:54294        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54298        127.0.0.1:54299        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54301        127.0.0.1:54302        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54302        127.0.0.1:54301        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54314        127.0.0.1:54315        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54315        127.0.0.1:54314        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54487        127.0.0.1:54486        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54488        127.0.0.1:54489        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54508        127.0.0.1:54509        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54650        127.0.0.1:54651        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54689        127.0.0.1:54690        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54690        127.0.0.1:54689        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54692        127.0.0.1:54693        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54695        127.0.0.1:54696        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54696        127.0.0.1:54695        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54720        127.0.0.1:54722        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54724        127.0.0.1:54725        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54725        127.0.0.1:54724        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54726        127.0.0.1:54728        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54728        127.0.0.1:54726        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54730        127.0.0.1:54731        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54733        127.0.0.1:54734        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54734        127.0.0.1:54733        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54735        127.0.0.1:54736        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54739        127.0.0.1:54740        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54740        127.0.0.1:54739        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54743        127.0.0.1:54744        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54744        127.0.0.1:54743        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54771        127.0.0.1:54772        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54772        127.0.0.1:54771        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54774        127.0.0.1:54775        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54775        127.0.0.1:54774        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54777        127.0.0.1:54778        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54778        127.0.0.1:54777        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54780        127.0.0.1:54781        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54781        127.0.0.1:54780        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54783        127.0.0.1:54784        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54784        127.0.0.1:54783        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54786        127.0.0.1:54787        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54787        127.0.0.1:54786        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54789        127.0.0.1:54790        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54790        127.0.0.1:54789        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54792        127.0.0.1:54793        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54795        127.0.0.1:54796        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54796        127.0.0.1:54795        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54799        127.0.0.1:54800        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54800        127.0.0.1:54799        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54810        127.0.0.1:54811        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54811        127.0.0.1:54810        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54860        127.0.0.1:54861        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54861        127.0.0.1:54860        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54865        127.0.0.1:54866        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54866        127.0.0.1:54865        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54867        127.0.0.1:54868        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54872        127.0.0.1:54873        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54873        127.0.0.1:54872        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54875        127.0.0.1:54876        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54876        127.0.0.1:54875        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54878        127.0.0.1:54879        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54881        127.0.0.1:54882        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54882        127.0.0.1:54881        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54884        127.0.0.1:54885        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54885        127.0.0.1:54884        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54887        127.0.0.1:54888        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54888        127.0.0.1:54887        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54890        127.0.0.1:54891        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54891        127.0.0.1:54890        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54892        127.0.0.1:54893        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54893        127.0.0.1:54892        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54896        127.0.0.1:54897        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54897        127.0.0.1:54896        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54898        127.0.0.1:54899        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54899        127.0.0.1:54898        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54902        127.0.0.1:54903        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54903        127.0.0.1:54902        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54905        127.0.0.1:54906        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54906        127.0.0.1:54905        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:49760     118.136.171.26:58982   LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.1.11:50200     74.125.71.83:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:50856     74.125.71.139:80       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:51124     14.56.22.241:34819     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:51127     2.90.14.154:41705      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:51418     90.191.19.233:51006    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:51527     76.125.75.32:32374     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    192.168.1.11:51687     90.231.112.185:60662   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:52255     81.49.46.75:50455      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:52575     2.176.222.3:15466      LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.1.11:52765     24.7.23.134:53097      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:52769     219.248.129.190:45682  CLOSING
  TCP    192.168.1.11:52840     151.32.240.199:19876   LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.1.11:52843     80.63.25.8:36009       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:52922     78.184.233.91:22110    LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53020     81.102.70.200:26555    LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53029     70.114.20.97:6881      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53032     70.72.181.120:12056    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53184     211.219.127.167:38462  LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53439     24.92.153.172:21380    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53482     213.114.70.198:9159    LAST_ACK
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53525     74.125.236.39:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53581     74.125.235.17:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53592     212.179.38.73:80       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:53595     212.179.38.73:80       TIME_WAIT
 .168.1.11:54242     203.190.124.12:80      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54245     208.93.137.60:80       TIME_WAIT
   192.168.1.11:54779     98.145.236.70:62607    SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54782     94.59.17.237:21485     SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54785     94.56.244.71:33633     SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54788     94.56.240.92:21485     SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54791     93.143.12.113:36408    SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54801     91.140.71.54:12199     SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54803     85.193.226.168:16049   SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54812     217.218.49.124:62263   SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54863     2.32.47.101:51413      SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54869     188.53.185.45:35025    SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54874     218.212.133.200:59995  SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54877     196.215.41.209:18327   SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54883     116.203.184.53:13761   SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54886     99.192.105.71:41236    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54889     122.161.153.165:53857  SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54894     83.251.162.33:43254    SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54895     217.112.110.138:49701  SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54900     85.83.54.106:49122     SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54901     76.173.110.93:17232    SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54904     83.31.143.206:20334    SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:54907     83.204.27.138:6881     SYN_SENT
```

**after the issue comes;**
**

```
C:\Users\abhi>
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
C:\Users\abhi>netstat -a
Active Connections
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8009           abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:17235          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49156          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49183          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49192          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49196          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49214          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49217          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49236          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING

  continue approx... 100000 more entries(can not paste due to question body length restriction)

     127.0.0.1:843          abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         abhi-THINK:63659       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         abhi-THINK:63704       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         abhi-THINK:65319       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6498         abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6499         abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8005         abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10000        abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10501        abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10501        abhi-THINK:50123       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10502        abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10502        abhi-THINK:50124       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49158        abhi-THINK:49165       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49162        abhi-THINK:49166       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49165        abhi-THINK:49158       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49166        abhi-THINK:49162       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49169        abhi-THINK:49170       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49170        abhi-THINK:49169       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50123        abhi-THINK:10501       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50124        abhi-THINK:10502       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50332        abhi-THINK:64518       FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50333        abhi-THINK:50332       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51168        abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51308        abhi-THINK:51300       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60824        abhi-THINK:60868       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60868        abhi-THINK:60824       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63659        abhi-THINK:3306        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63704        abhi-THINK:3306        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64518        abhi-THINK:50332       CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64519        abhi-THINK:64518       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:65319        abhi-THINK:3306        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:139       abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.1.11:51312     hx-in-f18:https        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.11:59246     cm126:64411            FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    192.168.1.11:60988     ip-178-200-153-46:31650  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.11:64520     hx-in-f19:https        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.11.1:139       abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.50.1:139       abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:2869              abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:5357              abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49152             abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49153             abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49154             abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49155             abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49156             abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:51169            abhi-THINK:0           LISTENING
  UDP    0.0.0.0:68             *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5060           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:6771           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:7078           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:7079           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:17235          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:55979          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:59995          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:60838          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:60840          *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:52907        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:53737        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59319        *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.11:137       *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.11:138       *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.11:1900      *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.11:1900      *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.11:59316     *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.11:61895     *:*
  UDP    192.168.11.1:137       *:*
  UDP    192.168.11.1:138       *:*
  UDP    192.168.11.1:1900      *:*
  UDP    192.168.11.1:59317     *:*
  UDP    192.168.50.1:137       *:*
  UDP    192.168.50.1:138       *:*
  UDP    192.168.50.1:1900      *:*
  UDP    192.168.50.1:59318     *:*
  UDP    [::]:500               *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:4500              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*
  UDP    [::]:55979             *:*
  UDP    [::]:60839             *:*
  UDP    [::]:60841             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:59315            *:*
  UDP    [fe80::117c:e87a:ce63:ea4b%19]:1900  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::117c:e87a:ce63:ea4b%19]:59313  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::4db2:7f05:1496:9976%14]:1900  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::4db2:7f05:1496:9976%14]:59312  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::a9e0:25a0:f0c4:7bfa%20]:1900  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::a9e0:25a0:f0c4:7bfa%20]:59314  *:*
```

C:\Users\abhi>

Can anyone please help me understand this netstat? Now this issue comes very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are out of swap space.  If it restarting the application doesn't help, it suggests another application is using the memory. When you stop an application its free all the resources that application uses. i.e. the wrong application was restarted.

Can you determine how much free memory is available after you exit tomcat when this has happened? If it is low, what is the biggest consumer of memory?

Can you increase the swap space of the machine, or better increase the physical memory of the machine?

Can you reduce memory consumption of your other applications (or tomcat if it proves to be the issue, but it doesn't sound like it)